# jquery get multi select values from multiple select tags

Tags: jquery

I want to get multi select values from multiple select tags using jquery. getting values from class name will also be fine but i have 19 select tags with different id but same class names so i just want to get all value of any option value. 
I am trying something like that but all in vain. here .vals is the class name of each select tag while valsa is the class name of `<tr class="valsa">`. I am trying getting them by same tr class. please help

```
function Values(){

var val = $(".vals.valss.valsss").val();
alert(val);
    }
```

returns undefiened ......

Comment: <select name="sel_crbtype_essay" id="essay" class="vals" multiple="multiple" size="5" style="width:611px">
                    <option value="56" selected="selected">The City and the Man</option>
                    <option value="58" selected="selected">Roe v. Wade at 40</option>
                  </select>

Comment: @Napster i have posted the scenerio please help. i am explaining more to you that if i press remove button that resides any select tag, it returns me its value and remove it from select tag as well. thats what i want.

Comment: @Napsterplease do something like that. 3 multiselect tags -> each have one remove button -> when i press any remove button it return me the value of that select tag and remove it from select tag as well. please i want this.

Answer (score 0):

Try .map()

```
var a = $(".valsa .vals").map(function () {
    return [$(this).val()]
}).get();
alert(a);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gNfhF/)

Comment: <select name="sel_crbtype_essay" id="essay" class="vals" multiple="multiple" size="5" style="width:611px"> <option value="56" selected="selected">The City and the Man</option> <option value="58" selected="selected">Roe v. Wade at 40</option> </select>

Comment: i have posted the scenerio please help. i am explaining more to you that if i press remove button that resides any select tag, it returns me its value and remove it from select tag as well. thats what i want.

Comment: @user3040719 updated the answer the selector try now

Comment: brother thats sounds good. can you please do something like that. 3 multiselect tags -> each have one remove button -> when i press any remove button it return me the value of that  select tag and remove it from select tag as well. please i want this.

Comment: dear it always returns all values. i want 3 buttons -> if press button one it gives me his value and remove it from select tag as well. value should be its own NOT any other else select tag please.

Comment: @user3040719 for us to help you, you you need to help us first understanding and recreating the problem... so as I asked first edit the fiddle I created to recreate your problem and share it with us

Answer (score 0):

You can get the select boxes with the following JQuery code.

```
var selectBoxList = $('select.yourClass');
```

After that you need to loop through all of these select boxes and get the selected option like so.

```
selectBoxList.each(function()
{
  var selectedOption = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: <select name="sel_crbtype_essay" id="essay" class="vals" multiple="multiple" size="5" style="width:611px"> <option value="56" selected="selected">The City and the Man</option> <option value="58" selected="selected">Roe v. Wade at 40</option> </select> 3 multiselect tags -> each have one remove button -> when i press any remove button it return me the value of that select tag and remove it from select tag as well. please i want this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Something like this

```
$("option:selected").map(function(){ return this.value }).get();
```

Comment: <select name="sel_crbtype_essay" id="essay" class="vals" multiple="multiple" size="5" style="width:611px"> <option value="56" selected="selected">The City and the Man</option> <option value="58" selected="selected">Roe v. Wade at 40</option> </select> 3 multiselect tags -> each have one remove button -> when i press any remove button it return me the value of that select tag and remove it from select tag as well. please i want this.

Comment: I think no need of remove button, if their is a multi selectbox, then in $_REQUEST you will get only those data which are selected.

Comment: i do need remove button because i want to remove that option value from select tag and then want to get its values. please...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var values = [];
$('#.valsa .vals').each(function(i, selected){
    values[i] = $(selected).attr('value');
});
```

Comment: <select name="sel_crbtype_essay" id="essay" class="vals" multiple="multiple" size="5" style="width:611px"> <option value="56" selected="selected">The City and the Man</option> <option value="58" selected="selected">Roe v. Wade at 40</option> </select> 3 multiselect tags -> each have one remove button -> when i press any remove button it return me the value of that select tag and remove it from select tag as well. please i want this.

Comment: can you please help??